# How do I apply CSS to an HTML DIV tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble applying CSS to my div tag. I've added the style="my css" to the tag but it still won't apply. I will post both the div tag and the css I'm trying to apply but it will not render on here so I'm just looking for suggestions and I'll try it myself.

The div tag is a gallery and the CSS is to hide an image within that gallery.

The div tag:

```html
<div class="cz-embed-gallery" id="cz-embed-gallery4081"></div>
```

The CSS: .gutter-sizer ~ .grid-item:nth-of-type(3) { display: none !important }

Answer (score 1):

```
.gutter-sizer ~ .grid-item:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: none !important
}
```

This code does not target the element shown in the snippet. It targets the third element with the class grid-item underneath the element with the class gutter-size.

You must use

```
#cz-embed-gallery4081 {
    display: none
}
```

to target just this element or

```
.cz-embed-gallery {
    display: none
}
```

to target all elements with that class. Also, if you want to use inline CSS you can do as such:

```
<div class="cz-embed-gallery" id="cz-embed-gallery4081" style="display: none"></div>
```

Comment: The <div> tag is a gallery and the  CSS: .gutter-sizer ~ .grid-item:nth-of-type(3) { display: none !important } is to hide an image within that gallery. I'm not sure if that would change the codes you have given me or not just trying to clarify what exactly the CSS is supposed to be doing. Thank you.